# TCP connect error during parallel execution

Tags: linux, cluster-computing

Parallel execution of a program gives me error.

```
 TCP connect error: ECONNREFUSED.
 DDI Process 41: error code 911
 TCP: Connect failed. node2 -> master:36883.
 TCP connect error: ECONNREFUSED.
 TCP connect error: ECONNREFUSED.
 TCP connect error: ECONNREFUSED.
 TCP connect error: ECONNREFUSED.
 TCP connect error: ECONNREFUSED.
```

I guess that this is due to some internal firewall of ubuntu because I am using a separate switch with no Internet connection.

I have used different information to open the port and allow ssh via ufw, but still I am getting the same error.

Could you please let me know how to overcome this problem?

Which command about iptables should I run on master and other nodes?

Comment: where You're trying to connect? what is the application? What is the port?

Comment: in order to help to open port on ufw and etc I require to give more info. what is serverside app? which port You're trying to connect? what is output of: `ufw status` ?